# Spring Boot - Embedded Tomcat - @WebListener, scanned by @ServletComponentScan, adds a filter and gets java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat8, servlet-3.0

Supposedly we can use `@ServletComponentScan` to add standard servlet components annotated with `@WebListener`, `@WebFilter` and so on.

In my case I have a `@WebListener` that adds dynamically a filter:

```
@WebListener
public class FilterConfigurerListener implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {   
        try{
            ...
            ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();
            Dynamic rcf = sc.addFilter("myFilter", MyFilter.class);
```

The `addFilter()` call throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called from a ServletContextListener that was not defined in web.xml, a web-fragment.xml file nor annotated with @WebListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$NoPluggabilityServletContext.addFilter(StandardContext.java:6639)
    at com.whatever.FilterConfigurerListener.contextInitialized(FilterConfigurerListener.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My Spring Boot App is annotated as said in the docs:

```
@ServletComponentScan(basePackageClasses=FilterConfigurerListener.class)
@SpringBootApplication
public class MySpringBootApplication {
```

Having a look at `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext` I can see that this implementation doesn't allow adding a filter:

```
    @Override
    public javax.servlet.FilterRegistration.Dynamic addFilter(
            String filterName, Class<? extends Filter> filterClass) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                sm.getString("noPluggabilityServletContext.notAllowed"));
    }
```

How can we achieve this then?

Comment: Why not just add the filter as a bean in your Spring Boot application?

Comment: 'cause the `FilterConfigurerListener` contains some reusable logic. It's part of a library that is used both in Spring Boot apps and normal JEE apps.

Comment: I suspect auto detection won't work and you would  `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` which adds it to the container instead of auto detecting it. You might need to wrap it in a `ServletContainerInitializer` to have it executed.

Comment: For your spring app could extend the `FilterConfigurerListener` in order to use it the "spring way" and be done with?